# Accessing an element of an array in TSX

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a TSX file, with a state including:

```
tickets: Ticket[],
```

I now want to change one specific element inside the array, and reset the state, my idea:

```
onClick = (ticket: Ticket, i: number) => {
            var newTitle = window.prompt('hello')
            ticket.title = newTitle ? newTitle : ticket.title
            var tickets = [this.state.tickets]
            tickets[i] = ticket

            // set state 
    }
```

Besides the usual "OBject could be undefined" errors, I'm mainly getting stuck at:

```
Type 'Ticket' is missing the following properties from type 'Ticket[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2740
```

It's as if they still consider `tickets[i]` to be of type `Tickets[]`. (I've done other checks and that seems to be the problem).

Do you know why this is the case? And how can still achieve my goal?

Thank you

Comment: `tickets[i] = ticket` <-- This is a mutation of state!  don't do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot that's wrong here including multiple mutations of state.

#### Array of Arrays

The particular error that you've posted:

```
Type 'Ticket' is missing the following properties from type 'Ticket[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.
```

Is caused by this line:

```
var tickets = [this.state.tickets]
```

You are taking the `array` of tickets from state **and putting it into an `array`**.  This variable `tickets` is an array with one element where that element is the array from your state.  In typescript terms, it is `[Ticket[]]` or `Ticket[][]`.  So each element of that array should be `Ticket[]` instead of `Ticket`.  When you try to set an element with a `Ticket` then you get an error that it should be `Ticket[]`.

#### State Mutations

As a rule of thumb, don't mutate anything in React if you aren't **certain** that it's safe.  Just setting `ticket.title` is an illegal mutation of state which will prevent your app from re-rendering properly.  The `Ticket` object that is passed to `onClick` is (presumably) the same object as the one in your `state` so **you cannot mutate it**.

Instead, we use array.map (which creates a copy of the array) to either return the same `Ticket` object or a copied one if we are changing it.  We don't actually need the `ticket` as an argument.  If the tickets have some unique property like an `id` then you could also pass just the `ticket` and not `i`.

```
onClick = (i: number) => {
  const newTitle = window.prompt("hello");
  if (newTitle) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      tickets: prevState.tickets.map((ticket, index) =>
        index === i ? { ...ticket, title: newTitle } : ticket
      )
    }));
  }
};
```